# Inhertitance + using object (this) as an argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, this

Edit: Added code from headings file.

Right now I'm working on some kind of simulation, and some problems occured. 
I have some classes like this one below:

```
#ifndef CARTYLERIA_H
#define CARTYLERIA_H
#include "cjednostka.h"
#include "cnieruchome.h"
#include "battlewindow.h"

class BattleWindow;

class CArtyleria : public CJednostka, public CNieRuchome <------ error line
{
public:
    CArtyleria();
    void rysuj(BattleWindow *okno);
};

#endif // CARTYLERIA_H
```

And when I try to compile there is an error in marked line :

> expected class-name before "," token

Everything was working properly until I add pointer to BattleWindow object.

Is it good practice to call CArtyleria method with

> this

in BattleWindow class object?

Cjednostka.h :

```
 #include "battlewindow.h"

    class CJednostka
    {
    public:
        CJednostka();
        virtual void rysuj (BattleWindow *okno) =0;
}
```

CNieRuchome.h:

```
class CNieRuchome
{
public:
    CNieRuchome();
protected:
    int PozycjaX;
    int PozycjaY;
};
```

And battlewindow.h:

```
#include <coddzial.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "ctimer.h"
#include "cpotyczka.h"
#include "cjednostka.h"

namespace Ui {
class BattleWindow;
}
class CPotyczka;
class BattleWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CPotyczka *potyczka;
    void tworz_oddzial();
    explicit BattleWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~BattleWindow();
    std::vector <QGraphicsPixmapItem*> items_vector;
    void dodaj_jednostki(std::vector<QString> jednostki, QString frakcja);
    void rysuj_jednostke(QString jednostka, QString frakcja, int x, int y);

private slots:

    void on_now();

private:

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    Ui::BattleWindow *ui;
    CTimer *timer;


    void rysuj_jednostki(QString frakcja);
    void rysuj_plansze ();
    void rysuj_flagi ();
    void usun_jednostke (QGraphicsPixmapItem *item);
    std::list<CJednostka*> jednostki_do_narysowania;
};
```

And what I want to do is:

calling method for objects in STL list `std::list<CJednostka*> jednostki_do_narysowania;`

Right now it is realized as below:

```
for(std::list <CJednostka*>::iterator it=jednostki_do_narysowania.begin();it!=jednostki_do_narysowania.end();++it){

        (*it)->rysuj(this);
```

Comment: So you added the `okno` argument and then you got an error for the line which defines the base classes? That doesn't sound right. As it stands, you have not provided enough code. We don't know what's in your three `*.h` files.

Comment: A common cause for this is that one of the include files in turn includes this file (a circular include), and the error occurs when the file is read a second time with the include guard already defined.

Comment: if you forward declarate battlewindow, you can delete the include statement. that will help probably.

Comment: Try removing the include of "battlewindow.h" as you already forward declare the class BattleWindow and you only pass as a pointer so complete definition is not needed. Btw stick to one languague in your code, mixing two is hardly a good idea ;)

Comment: like I said before. But you are right with the language. It is very hard to read code and you have no idea about what the code should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code.

First of all the problem you might have compiling is because you are missing the semicolon like Martin Broadhurst noticed in his answer.

Also you have a circular dependency between `cjednostka.h` and `battlewindow.h`.

Since cjednostka.h has only an interface class remove the include and add a forward declaration for `class BattleWindow` like you did in the `cartyleria.h`

Next problem is that you create a pure virtual interface for CJednostka but it doesn't have a virtual destructor. This is very bad and will eventually lead to improper destruction of object through base pointer.

Try this in cjednostka.h

```
#ifndef CJEDNOSTKA_H
#define CJEDNOSTKA_H
class CJednostka
{
public:
  CJednostka();
  virtual ~CJednostka() = default;
  virtual void rysuj (BattleWindow *okno) =0;
};
#endif
```

Also I recommend using either header  guards in all header files or #pragma once. Just stick to one option and do so in each header.

Another problem with the headers is that in one of them you include your own header as `#include <coddzial.h>` instead of `#include "coodzial.h"` this might lead to a problems as there is a difference in <> vs " ". The first one searched the library Include path the latter looks for the file relative to your project files and this is most likely what you want.

Lastly a suggestion in 90% of scenarios vectors are superior to lists and I have a strong feeling you don't need list. I recommend checking again on the differences between the two.

Comment: Guys, I'm trying to fix indicated problems, but there several additional issues. When I add class declaration in parent class: CJednostka is it necessary to do it again in inherited classes, have they knowledge and acces to it?

Comment: @BBq read a book or a tutorial on C++ classes and Inheritance. I am not sure what you mean by 'add class declaration in parent class'.